# I am tryig to automate a GUI Application through Python, using pyautogui, but when i use"locateCenterOnScreen" its gettig error?

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui as py

x,y=py.locateCenterOnScreen(r"C:\Users\vivek-kumar-singh\Desktop\python\Sonata\Start001.PNG")

py.click(x,y)
```

When I run this code sometime its work but after sometime its getting error:

```
return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: locateCenterOnScreen() function probably didn't find your image on screen, so it returns Nones. why not show the error completely, as it's not clear where return statement comes from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I know that locateCenterOnScreen() is not finding my image on screen but why? because same code sometimes it works but sometime it does not work why? I'll tell you what i am trying to do..1:i have a GUI application which i  want to automate. 2:i have to click on that button every time so, what i did is i have taken a screenshot of that particular button and saved in other folder and calling that by using locatecenterOnscreen() function but sometimes its getting error. Please suggest a suitable way to do this.